# phpmyadmin in vtiger missing extentions

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, vtiger

trying to use phpmyadmin with vtiger and getting a lot of missing extension errors. I have uncommented the extensions it requires in php.ini and there in the extension folder within vtiger but still comes up with errors, anyone got any other troubleshooting methods?

Comment: What errors are you getting exactly and where?

Comment: Hi, sorry for late reply. A restart seems to have got rid of the errors but now I get '#2005 Cannot log in to the MySQL server' with the same login settings. I was able to login before just got errors. I have SQLbuddy setup too with the same settings and that is able to gain access so pretty sure the login settings are correct!